# How to calculate Average of dates in groupby Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with more than 500K rows and 20 columns. I am trying to determine the frequency in which the `personId` receives something based on the `date_received` column, all of the other columns are irrelevant for this task but usefull for subsequent tasks.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      personId       |  date_Recieved   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |   2 feb 2016     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |   4 feb 2016     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |   6 feb 2016     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |   10 dec 2016    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |   1 jan 2017     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |   20 jan 2017    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The `date_received` is of type `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` I am looking for something like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      personId       |  Frequency       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      2 days      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     20.5 days    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

So in average person 1 recieves something every 2 days and person two recieves something every 20.5 days.

I tried using the `groupby` function but still haven't been able to get the response with my dataframe.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I would try using timedelta function, and apply it in a group by function. i.e. group, then sort based date, then for i+th row i do time delta. then you can use the usual average

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `groupby` and `lambda`

```
df.groupby('personId').date_Recieved.apply(lambda x: x.diff().dropna().mean())

personId
1    2 days 00:00:00
2   20 days 12:00:00
Name: date_Recieved, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

***setup***

```
txt = """
      personId         date_Recieved   
          1             2 feb 2016     
          1             4 feb 2016     
          1             6 feb 2016     
          2             10 dec 2016    
          2             1 jan 2017     
          2             20 jan 2017    
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', parse_dates=[1])
```